# Paginate with GH Pages's default plugins?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-paginator

I'm trying to populate my small blog on GH Pages. I'm stuck at Jekyll paginating.

Here's my `_config.yml`:

```
theme: jekyll-theme-cayman

title: iBug @ GitHub
url: https://ibug.github.io/
tagline: The small personal site for iBug
description: The small personal site for iBug
author: iBug
show_downloads: false

plugins:
  - jekyll-paginate
  - jekyll-redirect-from
  - jekyll-mentions
  - jekyll-seo-tag

paginate: 5
paginate_path: "/blog/page:num/"
```

And here's the content of the only post there:

```
---
layout: blog
permalink: /p/1
---

# Test Post

Nothing here
```

I want a paginated index page on `/blog`, and succeeding pages on `/blog/page#` (where `#` is a number). I copied a sample `index.html` and placed it at `/blog/index.html` in my repo.

But when I navigate to https://ibug.github.io/blog , it just show up like this:

> {% if paginator.total_pages > 1 %}
>   {% if paginator.previous_page %} [« Prev](https://ibug.github.io/blog/%7B%7B%20paginator.previous_page_path%20%7C%20prepend:%20site.baseurl%20%7C%20replace:%20'//',%20'/'%20%7D%7D) {% else %} « Prev {% endif %} {% for page in (1..paginator.total_pages) %} {% if page == paginator.page %} *{{ page }}* {% elsif page == 1 %} [{{ page }}](https://ibug.github.io/blog/%7B%7B%20paginator.previous_page_path%20%7C%20prepend:%20site.baseurl%20%7C%20replace:%20'//',%20'/'%20%7D%7D) {% else %} [{{ page }}](https://ibug.github.io/blog/%7B%7B%20site.paginate_path%20%7C%20prepend:%20site.baseurl%20%7C%20replace:%20'//',%20'/'%20%7C%20replace:%20':num',%20page%20%7D%7D) {% endif %} {% endfor %} {% if paginator.next_page %} [Next »](https://ibug.github.io/blog/%7B%7B%20paginator.next_page_path%20%7C%20prepend:%20site.baseurl%20%7C%20replace:%20'//',%20'/'%20%7D%7D) {% else %} Next » {% endif %}
>   {% endif %}

Reading the GH documentation, I learned that `jekyll-paginate` is a default plugin and cannot be disabled, so it shouldn't work this way.

I also have a dummy post at `/_posts/2018-03-01-first-post.md`, and it correctly shows up at https://ibug.github.io/2018/03/01/first-post

I don't want to install a Ruby dev environment and other stuff. I want to use only GH Pages's builtin functionality.

Can I get an index at `/blog` and `/blog/pageN`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your source code, this likely is an issue with the `index.html` file within your blog subdirectory.

You need to include front matter, even if it contains no key/value data, within any file you want processed by Jekyll. Without this, Jekyll assumes that it's a static asset and will just copy it over directly into your _site directory upon build.

Adding this at the top of your `index.html` file should fix it:

```
---
---
content here
```

You'll also want to be sure you're actually showing posts on that page and not just the pagination navigation. So be sure to include something like this above it:

```
{% for post in paginator.posts %}
  <h1><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
  <p class="author">
    <span class="date">{{ post.date }}</span>
  </p>
  <div class="content">
    {{ post.content }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

As a side note, you may want to look into [setting defaults](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#front-matter-defaults) within your `_config.yml` for post permalinks. It can be a lot cleaner than defining the link on every post.

Comment: Can you also tell me why `theme: jekyll-theme-cayman` isn't applied to my blog posts?

Comment: @iBug It looks like you're specifying the 'blog' layout for your post, but the Cayman theme only has a 'default' layout option ([view here](https://github.com/pages-themes/cayman/tree/master/_layouts)). So you'll want to set the layout value for each of your page's front matter to use 'default'. You can make this easier by setting up [global defaults](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#front-matter-defaults).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.